# UDP Broadcast and Receive

Tags: java, udp

I have a Java class intended to facilitate connections between computers without the need for explicitly defining peer addresses.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.MulticastSocket;
import java.net.SocketException;

public class Broadcasts {

    private final Runnable receiver;
    private final Runnable sender;
    private boolean run = true;

    public Broadcasts(TheThing parent) {
        receiver = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                byte data[] = new byte[0];
                DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length);
                try {
                    DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
                    while (run) {
                        socket.receive(packet);
                        parent.newAddress(packet.getAddress());
                    }
                } catch (SocketException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    parent.quit();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    parent.quit();
                }
            }
        };
        sender = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                byte data[] = new byte[0];
                DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length);
                try {
                    MulticastSocket socket = new MulticastSocket();
                    socket.setBroadcast(true);
                    socket.joinGroup(Globals.publicAddress);
                    while (run) {
                        socket.send(packet);
                        Thread.sleep(Globals.UDPINTERVAL);
                    }
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    parent.quit();
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    parent.quit();
                }
            }
        };
        new Thread(receiver).start();
        new Thread(sender).start();
    }

    public void quit() {
        run = false;
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
java.net.SocketException: Not a multicast address
    at java.net.MulticastSocket.joinGroup(MulticastSocket.java:310)
    at the.thing.Broadcasts$2.run(Broadcasts.java:42)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The problem I am facing is the address defined as `Globals.publicAddress` *is* a multicast address. What am I missing here?

`Globals.publicAddress` is obtained with the following method. It *should* be the DHCP assigned address:

```
private static InetAddress getPublicIface() {
    InetAddress result = null;
    Enumeration e;
    try {
        e = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
    } catch (SocketException ex) {
        return null;
    }
    while (e.hasMoreElements() && result == null) {
        NetworkInterface n = (NetworkInterface) e.nextElement();
        Enumeration ee = n.getInetAddresses();
        while (ee.hasMoreElements()) {
            InetAddress i = (InetAddress) ee.nextElement();;
            if (i.getHostAddress().startsWith("192.168.")) {
                result = i;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
return result;
```

I have also tried the following method to obtain a valid broadcasting address:

```
private static InetAddress getPublicIface() {
    InetAddress result = null;
    Enumeration e;
    try {
        e = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
    } catch (SocketException ex) {
        return null;
    }
    while(e.hasMoreElements() && result == null) {
        NetworkInterface iface = (NetworkInterface) e.nextElement();
        try {
            if(iface == null || iface.isLoopback() || !iface.isUp() ||
                    iface.isVirtual() || !iface.supportsMulticast())
                continue;
        } catch (SocketException ex) {
            continue;
        }
        Iterator it = iface.getInterfaceAddresses().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            InterfaceAddress address = (InterfaceAddress) it.next();
            if(address == null || address.getBroadcast() == null)
                continue;
            result = address.getBroadcast();
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: @MartinKonecny The address is the address in use within my LAN.

Comment: If the address is in use, it can't be used for broadcast.  Broadcast is normally indicated by IP address FF.FF.FF.FF.  What is the address you are using, please?  It makes a difference.

Comment: @markspace 192.168.1.5 And by in-use, I mean it is the address assigned to my computer from my router.

Comment: You definately can't broadcast to your own IP address.

Comment: https://www.countryipblocks.net/identifying-the-network-and-broadcast-address-of-a-subnet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't know about `NetworkInterface`, so that was a cool new thing for me.  So I grepped around and put together some code that seems to work.  It needs clean-up, but it runs on my system and seems to actually broadcast.

Salient points:

1. You don't need to listen on the broadcast address.  Since it's broadcast, you'll get it no matter what IP address you listen on.
2. You do have to send to the broadcast address, and for some reason this seems to work only as a parameter of `DatagramPacket`, never `DatagramSocket`.  I dunno why, but that's how the API seems to want it.

Good luck.

```
public class BroadcastTest
{
   private static final int RANDOM_PORT = 4444;

   public static void main( String[] args )
           throws Exception
   {
      InetAddress addr = getBroadcastAddrs().get(0);
      System.err.println( addr );
      new Thread( new BroadcastServer( RANDOM_PORT ) ).start();
      DatagramSocket dsock = new DatagramSocket();
      byte[] send = "Hello World".getBytes( "UTF-8" );
      DatagramPacket data = new DatagramPacket( send, send.length, addr, RANDOM_PORT );
      dsock.send( data );
   }

   public static List<InetAddress> getBroadcastAddrs() throws SocketException {
      Set<InetAddress> set = new LinkedHashSet<>();
      Enumeration<NetworkInterface> nicList = NetworkInterface.
              getNetworkInterfaces();
      for( ; nicList.hasMoreElements(); ) {
         NetworkInterface nic = nicList.nextElement();
         if( nic.isUp() && !nic.isLoopback() )  {
            for( InterfaceAddress ia : nic.getInterfaceAddresses() )
               set.add( ia.getBroadcast() );
         }
      }
      return Arrays.asList( set.toArray( new InetAddress[0] ) );

   }
}

class BroadcastServer implements Runnable {
   private final int port;

   public BroadcastServer( int port )
   {
      this.port = port;
   }

   @Override
   public void run()
   {
      try {
         DatagramSocket dsock = new DatagramSocket( port );
         DatagramPacket data = new DatagramPacket( new byte[2048], 2048 );
         dsock.receive( data );
         System.out.println( new String( data.getData(), "UTF-8" ) );
      } catch( SocketException ex ) {
         Logger.getLogger( BroadcastServer.class.getName() ).
                 log( Level.SEVERE, null, ex );
      } catch( IOException ex ) {
         Logger.getLogger( BroadcastServer.class.getName() ).
                 log( Level.SEVERE, null, ex );
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: There is no DatagramSocket API that sends to an IP address. Just one that sends a packet. You have to put the target address into the DatagramPacket. That's how it works.

Comment: @EJP So why does DatagramSocket have two ctors that take IP addresses, plus bind() and connect() methods that also take IP addresses?  It's rather confusing.

Comment: @markspace the reason is that those are "listener" sockets. The API is crappy, so you have the same class for send and receive

Comment: @markspace can you explain from where you get getBroadcastAddrs()

Comment: @YLS The code is right there.  For all network interfaces, if it's "up" and not the loop-back address, I add them to a list.  Then I arbitrarily select the first one, because it's unlikely that a desktop system has more than one valid network.